# Color code sharepoint Online calendar view

Tags: javascript, list-view, custom-list, calendar, client-side-rendering

I have a custom list in which i have created a calendar view.

I want to color the calendar items based on a choice column. In SP2010, I had a JavaScript doing this but in SP Online, I am not able to achieve this.

Please note: Calendar Overlay option is not available as this is a custom list.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below link

COLOR CODED CALENDAR IN SHAREPOINT ONLINE USING JAVASCRIPT

http://www.sharepointjunkies.com/color-coded-calendar-sharepoint-online-using-javascript/

Comment: This article helped me with my query.